# Table alignment is not getting fixed

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have created an html table for designing the invoice for my company. I want the second row to be aligned inline with the upper row and the columns in the second row have widths according to me. I want this invoice to be printable on A4 sheet. Herewith attaching the screen shot:

[image]

Here is the code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
         table td {
                        border-right: 1px solid #555;

                        border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
         }

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table style="border: 1px solid;">
            <tr>
                <td style="border-bottom:none;">
                    <table style="border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 
 0;"><tr><td style="border-right:none;"><b>ITG TELEMATICS PRIVATE 
LIMITED(2014-16)</b><br>
                        A-12/3, Naraina Phase-1<br>
                        Industrial Area,Near PVR Cinema<br>
                        New Delhi-110028<br>
                        GSTIN/UIN: 07AACCI2674M1Z9<br>
                        CIN:U74900DL2010PTC200755<br>
                        E-Mail: accounts@g-trac.in</td></tr>
                        <tr><td style="border-right:none; border-bottom: 
none;">Buyer<br>
                                <b>Snowman Logistics Ltd</b><br>
                        Old Madras Rd,Virgonagar Industrial Estate,<br>
                        Aavalahalli Bengaluru, Karnataka 560049<br>
                        Karnataka, Code:29<br>
                        GSTIN/UIN:29AAFCS3514H1ZC</td>
                        </tr></table>
                </td>
                <td style="border-right: none ;border-bottom:none; vertical-align:top;">
                    <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;">
                        <tr><td>Invoice No.<br><b>ITG/17-18/0001</b></td>
                            <td style="border-right: none ; border-spacing: 0;">Dated<br><b>1-Jul-2017</b></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Delivery Note<br/><br/></td><td style="border-right: none; vertical-align: top; ">Mode/Terms of Payment</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Supplier's Ref<br><b>ITG/17-18/0001</b></td><td style="border-right: none ;vertical-align: top;">Other Reference(s)</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Buyer's Order No.<br><br></td><td style="border-right: none ;vertical-align: top;">Dated</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Dispatch Document No.<br><br></td><td style="border-right: none ;vertical-align: top;">Delivery Note Date</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Dispatched Through<br><br></td><td style="border-right: none ;vertical-align: top;">Destination</td></tr>
                        <tr ><td  colspan="2" style="border-right: none ; border-bottom: none;">Terms of Delivery<br><br><br></td></tr>


                    </table>
                </td>

            </tr>


            <tr>
                <table>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-size: 12px;border-left: 1px solid;border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0;">Sl<br>No.</td>
                        <td style="font-size: 12px;" >Description of Goods</td>
                        <td style="font-size: 12px;">HSN/SAC</td>
                        <td style="font-size: 12px;">Quantity</td>
                        <td style="font-size: 12px;">Rate</td>
                        <td style="font-size: 12px;">per</td>
                        <td style="font-size: 12px;">Amount</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                </table>
            </tr>


            <tr>

            </tr>


            <tr>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear and "second row" is ambiguous referring to the screenshot. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: second row is the one which is going ahead of the alignment

Comment: @AhsN please help

Comment: You have tables inside tables. You cannot have another table inside a table tag. Use `colspan` and `rowspan` to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Your Question is not clear.. at least make one rough sketch how you want your table to be look like and upload it.. so we can try to help you.